# Python exec() Syntax Error with groupby().agg()

Tags: python-3.x

I want to run a for loop to create output dataframes (table_14, table_15) where the names have the same suffices as the input dataframes (df14, df15). I know it is recommended using list or dict but I found exec() is very direct and does exactly what I want to do:

```
dfs=[df14, df15]

for i, suffix in enumerate(range(14,16)):
    exec(f"table_{suffix} = dfs[i].groupby(dfs[i]['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d'))['Data_Value'].agg({np.max, np.min})")
    exec(f'x = len(table_{suffix})')
    print(f'table_{suffix} has {x} records \n\n')
```

But the problem is its conflict with .agg. I got a [image: syntax error]

I suspect it's the wrapper {} inside of .agg() that causes the error. It makes exec() thinks it's a placeholder. Is there no way to use this construct to create new dataframes as expected?

Comment: You have to escape the `{}`. Change `{np.max, np.min}` to `{{np.max, np.min}}`.

Comment: Pleae do not post pictures of text.

Comment: I solved it:     ```for i, suffix in enumerate(range(14,16)):
    exec(f"table_{suffix} = dfs[i].groupby(dfs[i]['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d'))['Data_Value'].agg({{'TMAX': np.max, 'TMIN': np.min}})")
    exec(f'x = len(table_{suffix})')
    print(f'table_{suffix} has {x} records \n\n')
    exec(f"print(table_{suffix}.head(),'\\n\\n', table_{suffix}.tail(), '\\n\\n')") ```